# Simplify SQL Query which aggregates per year

Tags: postgresql, optimization

This query works, but uses `TO_CHAR(date_created, 'YYYY')` three times.

Is there a way to simplify this query?

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(date_created, 'YYYY'), count(*) 
FROM ticket 
WHERE date_created >= '2013-01-01' and 
      date_created <= '2017-06-01' 
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(date_created, 'YYYY') 
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(date_created, 'YYYY');
```

Result:

```
 to_char | count  
---------+--------
 2013    | 441500
 2014    | 574660
 2015    | 247910
 2016    | 601234
```

I want to simplify it. Performance does not matter at all (in this case). Unfortunately I found no matching tag for this question. I took "optimization".

I use PostgreSQL

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? (`TO_CHAR` suggests Oracle)

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ I updated the question.

Comment: Unrelated, but: I prefer using `extract(year from date_created)` that way the "year" is really a number, not a character string

Comment: Another handy function is [date_trunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC).

Comment: Why do you want to "simplify" it? It's a pretty simple query. You don't need to use the expression (`TO_CHAR(date_created, 'YYYY')`) three times, only 2. If you alias the column (say `year_created`) in the select list, you can use it in `ORDER BY`, with `ORDER BY year_created`.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Why I want to simplify? Good question. I like it simple and easy to understand. If I can use it only twice, not three times, great. Please write it as answer, and I will up-vote it.

Answer (score 1):

A [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) can be used in this case:

```
WITH yourdata as (
    SELECT TO_CHAR(date_created, 'YYYY') AS tc_date_created
    FROM ticket
    WHERE date_created >= '2013-01-01' AND 
          date_created <= '2017-06-01' 
)
SELECT tc_date_created, count(*)
FROM yourdata 
GROUP BY tc_date_created
ORDER BY tc_date_created;
```

Comment: Or `extract(year from date_created)` as they are in Postgres ;)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: `extract()` is not only used in Postgres. It's standard SQL and also supported by other DBMS.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the original question was not tagged and Phil assumed it might be Oracle. Not sure if Oracle has `extract()`.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: Oracle does support the standard `extract()` function

Comment: Great thnx. I didn't know/